# Oracle SQL : Union and Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table ACCPLAN(PRIMARY KEY : ACCOUNT_ID)

```
ACCOUNT_ID                  PLAN_TYPE            OTHER_STUFF

ACC1                        PLAN_TYPE_ONE        ....
ACC2                        PLAN_TYPE_TWO        ....
ACC3                        PLAN_TYPE_ONE        ....
ACC4                        PLAN_TYPE_TWO        ...
```

I have one more table ACCTRANSACTION (PRIMARY KEY -> (ACCOUNT_ID,TRANSACTION_ID)

```
ACCOUNT_ID TRANSACTION_ID  TRANSACTION_AMOUNT TXN_TYPE

ACC1       1               100                TXN_TYPE_1
ACC1       2               300                TXN_TYPE_2
ACC2       1               400                TXN_TYPE_2
ACC3       1               400                TXN_TYPE_3
```

There are 5 fixed plan_types and 20 fixed txn_types.Only few transactions types are 
    possible for each plan_type.(For eg : TXN_TYPE_1 and TXN_TYPE_2 are possible for 
    PLAN_TYPE_ONE and  TXN_TYPE_2 and TXN_TYPE_3 are possible for PLAN_TYPE_TWO)

I am trying to retrieve the transaction information from ACCTRANSACTION and other
    details from ACCPLAN

This can be done in 2 ways

APPROACH 1

Retrieve for each plan_type and do an union

```
select ap.account_id,ap.other_stuff,at.transaction_amount
from accplan ap, acctransaction at
where ap.account_id =  at.account_id
and ap.plan_type = PLAN_TYPE_ONE
and at.txn_type in (TXN_TYPE_1,TXN_TYPE_2);

union

select ap.account_id,ap.other_stuff,at.transaction_amount
from accplan ap, acctransaction at
where ap.account_id =  at.account_id
and ap.plan_type = PLAN_TYPE_TWO
and at.txn_type in (TXN_TYPE_2,TXN_TYPE_3); 

union

...
```

APPROACH 2

Retrieve using one query for all plan_types

```
 select ap.account_id,ap.other_stuff,at.transaction_amount
    from accplan ap, acctransaction at
    where ap.account_id =  at.account_id
    and 
    ((ap.plan_type = PLAN_TYPE_ONE  and at.txn_type in (TXN_TYPE_1,TXN_TYPE_2))

    or

    (ap.plan_type = PLAN_TYPE_TWO and at.txn_type in (TXN_TYPE_2,TXN_TYPE_3));
```

which approach is better considering both tables have huge data?. Please suggest.

Comment: I vote to close because you question is opinion based and this here on SO is off-topic. You should run an explain plain on both queries and see which one is the best for your database.

Comment: I understand that "best" in this contexts only means fastest. This, in a know database (Oracle) can be measured and reproduced. 

Even if lots of things can affect the result( index, stats, version, configuration options, hardware) understanding the execution plan of the database can give you a good idea of what could be faster.

Anyway, there are periodically a lot of performance related questions that could be redirected to some stackexchange site. Is there anything in Meta about this?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should stop using the out-dated and old-fashioned implicit joins in the `where` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator (in the `from` clause). I also do agree that the second one is probably more efficient. If you do want the first one nonetheless you should use `UNION ALL` instead to avoid the overhead of removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Use joins. Unions require sorting the whole result and it is an expensive operation for your database.

Furthermore. It is better to read the table one time and do some complex checks with each record than reading it several times just to make smaller checks.

Disclaimer: I can imagine some very strange corner cases where the first query runs faster if the database query planner decides that the big condition is not selective enough and does not uses an index and each of the smaller one does use it. The bigger the number of rows the more I would use the second option.

Comment: +1 Good explanation and disclaimer.  It's worth noting that Oracle does have a few different transformations related to `UNION` but none of them apply here.  For example, the [USE_CONCAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABIAFIB) hint converts `OR` into `UNION ALL`, and [join factorization](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_join_factorization) can prevent re-reading large tables in `UNION ALL`.  Oddly, join factorization only works with *more* complicated scenarios and does not help with these simple queries.

Comment: Well, you can avoid the sorting when you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: UNION ALL is faster. He could use them if either he doesn't mind duplicates or if he is sure that there are not duplicates that can be the case.

Even with UNION ALL I would bet on JOINS with the explicit JOIN operator as you said.